# Understanding scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

So I am using `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve` function. I understood how it works for 2D matrices from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html). But when I apply this to 3D matrices it is giving results which I cannot interpret. For example:

```
In[80]: a = np.array([[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]])


In[81]: b = np.array([[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]],[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]])

In[82]: scimg.convolve(a, b, output = None, mode = 'constant')

Out[83]: 
array([[[ 16,  40,  48],
        [ 24,  60,  72],
        [ 16,  40,  48]],

       [[ 24,  60,  72],
        [ 36,  90, 108],
        [ 24,  60,  72]],

       [[ 16,  40,  48],
        [ 24,  60,  72],
        [ 16,  40,  48]]])
```

I understood convolution from this [post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/concept_of_convolution.htm). So according to me the (0, 0, 0) index should be 8. Similarly (0, 0, 1) should be 20. Where am I going wrong in the understanding?

**EDIT:** I would be grateful even if someone tells me how the module works for n-D (or channel) images with n-D filters.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is three-dimensional which makes it a bit harder to visualize so let me take the sample you linked from the official scipy documentation. To keep the output the same size as the input image, the kernel will start to slide over the input starting at position (-1,-1) relative to the input image. Areas the kernel does not overlap are treated as 0s when using parameters `mode='constant',cval=0.0` and the values of the kernel (red) are multiplied with the values of the input (black), summed up and put in the output. Keep in mind that in a convolutional operation [the kernel gets flipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution), then the first five steps of the convolution will look as follow (starting from top left to lower right):

```
1.step: 1*1+1*2+1*5+1*3 = 11
2.step: 0*1+1*2+1*0+1*5+1*3+1*0 = 10
...
```

[image]

In your example, the same principles are applied, the only difference is that you additionally also convolve along the third axis.